# Why State is preferred than Link in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and wanted to know that *Why State is preferred upon Link?*

-I want to redirect the user to another page, in that case does a state change makes more sense or adding Link would be equally good?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "State" and "Link" are in your question? Also, what more about what it is you are wanting to do?

Comment: If you have a seperate route for what you want to display then you'd use Link. Only if the different viewState is on the same route, you may handle it by using state.

Comment: Thank you folks, seems like I got the answer from Nabeel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the component with state change, then its a pretty wrong idea, you will face the following issues

1. When you refresh the page, it will go to the initial state page, solution: in this case you need to store your page state in Redux Store instead of local state.
2. You cannot go to a specific page, with a route, for example, you wanna go to user profile page, directly using a link, then you cannot go, because you will be directed to your initial state page